# How to add data in popup using primefaces and ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am new in JSF, facing a problem while executing GET AJAX request.

I have a icon with a counter (number), once I will do mouse over to the icon it shows a kind of small popup with small list (3 items), kind of same behavior as we have in Social networking sites (Notification icon). Till here All good. Now in my pop up at bottom side, I added a text says "Show more". This should get 3 more items/ notification from the DB via Ajax call and add the response in the popup (without closing the popup), then in total there should be 6 items.

I am not sure how exactly I can achieve this, Please help.

Using `<h:outputText value="show more}">` in my xhtml.
In my bean I have a method to `getMoreNotification()`.

Recently I tried with `<p:remoteCommand>`, but not sure how I can add responce/ data in popup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seek an in-built PrimeFaces component [`<p:dataScroller>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/loader.xhtml) instead. Put a button or something else to load data on demand such as `<f:facet name="loader"> <p:commandButton type="button" value="More" /></f:facet>`. It can also be loaded lazily, if needed.

Comment: Found primefaces component [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/loader.xhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that difficult

1. Create a list which is initially populated with 3 items
2. Create a `<p:overlay>` with IN that `<p:overlay>` e.g. a `<p:dataList>` that shows these list mentioned in 1. Give this component an id, e.g. 'notifications'
3. When clicking on the 'show more' commandLink, execute the `getMoreNotification()` via an `actionListener` and IN that method update the list mentioned in 1. Also make sure you have an update attribute that contains the value of the `<p:dataList>`.

Comment: But I think the `<p:dataScroller>` like @Tiny proposed and use that in a `<p:overlay>` could work to. Although you do get some markup then that you do not want (most likely removable with css)